# discord.js bot await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js

I don't know where I can put async. Help me please. I have a logs await is only valid in async function

```js
const args = message.content.split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === '.eval') {
 // Put your userID here
 if (message.author.id !== '505034363914682368') return;

 let evaled;
 try {
  evaled = await eval(args.join(' '));
  message.channel.send(inspect(evaled));
  console.log(inspect(evaled));
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.reply('there was an error during evaluation.');
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the keyword `await` is available only inside of `async` defined function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Basically, async/await is a sugar/abstraction on top of Promises. I'd suggest you to improve your knowledge of promises in JavaScript to be able to understand better the context of how async/await works.

Comment: In JS `eval()` not needs `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your `message` function is async.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
//                   ^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course await only works inside async functions. You can either use .then(callback) instead of async-await or convert the whole code to be an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) with the function declared as an async function and use await inside it.